# Sort Recoil atoms in atomFamily using properties in each one

Tags: typescript, react-native, recoiljs

I currently have 2 state variables defined like so:

```js
export const chatsAtom = atomFamily<Chat, string>({
    key: 'chatsAtom',
    default: undefined
})

export const chatIdsAtom = atom<string[]>({
    key: 'chatIdsAtom',
    default: []
})
```

I'm using `useRecoilCallback()` to add and update the values:

```js
const addChat = useRecoilCallback(
    ({set}) =>
    (chat:Chat) => {
        set(chatsAtom(chat.id), chat)
        set(chatIdsAtom, prev => [...prev, chat.id])
    }
)
```

Storing chats in a normal `atom` means I can sort using `setState(prev => [...prev].sort())`

My question is, seeing as there is no `get` method exposed by `useRecoilCallback()`, how can I implement something similar using the `atomFamily` and chat IDs?

More specifically, I want to be able to sort the most recently active chats to the top of my chat list. Meaning sorting by the most recent timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, implementing it directly within the `useRecoilCallback()` function is challenging due to the absence of the get method exposed by `useRecoilCallback()`. However, an alternative approach is available rather than attempting a direct implementation within `useRecoilCallback()`.

The simplest method involves creating a new atom with the necessary information for sorting the chat list, instead of managing chats using `chatsAtom`. By creating a new atom and performing sorting and filtering within it, you can achieve the desired functionality.

```
export const sortedChatsAtom = selector({
  key: 'sortedChatsAtom',
  get: ({ get }) => {
    const chatIds = get(chatIdsAtom);
    const sortedChats = chatIds.map(id => get(chatsAtom(id))).sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp);
    return sortedChats;
  }
});
```

In the above code, a selector is used to create `sortedChatsAtom`. This atom retrieves chat IDs from `chatIdsAtom`, fetches each chat from `chatsAtom`, and returns a sorted list based on the latest timestamp.

By using `useRecoilValue(sortedChatsAtom)`, you can easily access the sorted chat list.